# How to execute classes sequentially using java?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

*Following is my code:

```
private static Class<?>[] testClasses = new Class[] {
    LTest.class,        
    DTest.class,
    GTest.class,
    ATest.class, 
    BTest.class,
    STest.class,
    CTest.class,
};
```

I want to execute the testclasses sequentially, but not executed sequentially when i run it*

Comment: private List<Class<?>> selectedClasses = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();

Comment: please help me for to execute arraylist of class type sequentially.